# Unknown character at the end of string

Tags: c++, string

This is a practice problem from hackerrank: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/caesar-cipher-1.
My output matches with the expected output of the program but there is an unknown character at the end of output string.Can someone please tell me how does the unknown character occur at the end of string. 
Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<cstdio>
using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int k,n;
    string text;
    cin>>n;
    cin>>text;
    cin>>k;

    for (int i = 0; i <n; i++)
    { 
        if(text[i] != '\0') //check if the character is null
        {
            if(isalpha(text[i])) //check if the character is alphabet
            {
                int d=(int)text[i] ; //obtain the ascii value
                int t=d+k;           //obtain the encrypted value
                if(t>122)            //if the encrypted value of character is greater than 122
                {
                    int extra=t-122;
                    int letter=97 +(extra-1);
                    string ans= string()+char(letter);
                    cout<<ans;
                }

                string ans= string()+char(t); //print the encrypted character
                cout<<ans;
             }
             else              //if the character is not string, then print it just like that
            {
                 cout<<text[i];
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Output:    qmhhpi-Syxd

My Output:      qmhhpi-Syxd~

Comment: What is the input for this ?

Comment: Why read `n` when you know the length of `text`? Is `n` entered correctly for size of `text`?

Comment: Input: 11
middle-Outz
4

Comment: @crashmstr  Yes if n=11 then the string is middle-Outz (whose size is 11). The only reason n is read here because it is part of the problem statement and input format given.

Comment: okffng-Qwvb| is your output for the input given above.
http://ideone.com/Jt3gUv

Comment: *string ans= string()+char(t); 
                cout<<ans;* - These two lines could simply be `cout << char(t);` No need to create an empty string, concatenate it with a character, store that, and output the string, all instead of just outputting the character. Same with the other lines that do that.

Comment: @ABcDexter oops sorry I gave a different input. My mistake.

Comment: @chris You are right. char() typecaste is better, why use `string ans`??

Comment: @aiop_io There is a little flaw in your approach, wait for my answer :-)

Comment: @ABcDexter Ok. I am new to strings and I used string ans as it gave the right answer (no particular reason, I know it sounds silly but ya..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few bugs in your code:

1. In `if(t>122)`, you are checking if the encrypted character ( by Caesar cypher) has value greater than 122( ASCII for Z). But what if its value was originally in the range A-Z and then key was added. 
   Thus, these two lines are not correct. 
   `int extra=t-122;
    int letter=97 +(extra-1);`
2. Your code is incoherent. As in if you are already given the length of the string as `n`, then why are you using `if(text[i] != '\0')`. 
    Also, why use 
    `string ans= string()+char(t); cout<<ans;`. 
   As pointed out by @chris , these two lines could simply be  `cout << char(t);`
3. Since **K** can vary between **[0,100]**, it's better to take its MOD with 26. You can check the correct code here: [Ideone link](http://ideone.com/Jt3gUv)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there are two outputs of string `ans` in the loop. So when the current letter is `'z'` (the last letter of your input string) then at first the if statement is executed that prints letter `'d'` and then the statmenets

```
string ans= string()+char(t); //print the encrypted character
cout<<ans;
```

are also executed that output the initial value of t.

```
int t=d+k;
```

You should use `if-else` statement.

Take into account that the code is unsafe very redundant and uses magic numbers like for example `122` that make it unclear.

You should include header `<cctype>` because you are using function `isalpha` declared in this header.

```
#include <cctype>
```

Header `<cstdio>` should be removed because none declaration is used from this header.

To output a character there is no need to create an object of type `std::string`. For example instead of these statements

```
string ans= string()+char(t); //print the encrypted character
cout<<ans;
```

you could just write

```
cout << char( t );
```